# Trying to write a simple countdown loop in pairs with Ruby

Tags: ruby

This instructions are as follow:

> NUMBER CRUNCHER
>
> Write a method that takes a number as an argument
> If the number is greater than 20
> count down from the number by 2's
> If the number is less than 20
> count down from the number by 1's
> Display the numbers as they count down to 0.

I have written this, but it's not doing what it's supposed. Any help?

```
def num_cruncher(num)
count = num

until count == 0 do
    if num > 20
        puts count - 2
    else
        puts "#{count}"
    end
        count -= 1
  end
end
```

Comment: You are always only counting down by 1 here. `count - 2` doesn't change `count`. And `count -= 1` is executed each time through the loop regardless of the value of `count`. Your logic should (1) check the value of `count` and decrement it according to the rule you want, and then (2) print the current value of `count`.

Comment: What should happen when num is exactly 20?

Answer (score 2):

Here's your code, with as few changes as possible :

```
def num_cruncher(num)
  count = num

  until count < 0 do
    puts count
    if num > 20
      count -= 2
    else
      count -= 1
    end
  end
end

num_cruncher(10)
# 10
# 9
# 8
# 7
# 6
# 5
# 4
# 3
# 2
# 1
# 0

num_cruncher(21)
# 21
# 19
# 17
# 15
# 13
# 11
# 9
# 7
# 5
# 3
# 1
```

By extracting the if-statement outside of the loop, the code becomes a bit shorter :

```
def num_cruncher(num)
  if num > 20
    step = 2
  else
    step = 1
  end

  until num < 0 do
    puts num
    num -= step
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Numeric#step](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Numeric.html#method-i-step) here. Something like this:

```
def num_cruncher n
  s = n > 20 ? -2 : -1
  n.step(by: s, to: 0).entries
end

num_cruncher 23
#=> [23, 21, 19, 17, 15, 13, 11, 9, 7, 5, 3, 1]
```

Comment: @EricDuminil Great idea, have just refactored my code (think that's what you meant).

Comment: More verbose, but perhaps clearer: `n.step(by: -2, to: 0).entries`. Readers: [Enumerable#entries](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-entries) is the same (same C code) as [Enumerable#to_a](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-to_a).

Comment: @CarySwoveland good idea, have modified my answer with your suggestion.